# need to implement virtual buttons on xcode for my project/ way for users to interact with augmented objects

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, user-interaction

I am doing my research project in augmented reality and I want to allow users to touch my true/false buttons as displayed in the picture below in the camera's view and not the touchscreen. Is there any way that I can do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make virtual buttons you have several choices:

**1: (Experimental):** You could render a custom `UIView` with 2 Buttons on it.

**2nd:** Create two `SCNNodes` with an `SCNPlane Geometry` and then use an image for the true or false prompts.

**3rd:** Use `SCNText` as displayed in your image above.

If you opted for option number one there is no need to perform an `SCNHitTest`, as you can use `IBActions` to determine which one was tapped.

For the other options you will need to make use of an `SCNHitTest` which:

> looks for SCNGeometry objects along the ray you specify. For each
>   intersection between the ray and and a geometry, SceneKit creates a
>   hit-test result to provide information about both the SCNNode object
>   containing the geometry and the location of the intersection on the
>   geometry’s surface.

I won't go into the details of the 1st option with you as this is not a 'standard' nor widely adopted practice (if it all).

Lets look then first at using two `SCNNodes` as 'virtual buttons' with an `SCNPlaneGeometry`:

```
/// Creates A Menu With A True Or False Button Using SCNPlane Geometry
func createTrueOrFalseMenu(){

    //1. Create A Menu Holder
    let menu = SCNNode()

    //2. Create A True Button With An SCNPlane Geometry & Green Colour
    let trueButton = SCNNode();
    let trueButtonGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
    let greenMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    greenMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
    greenMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    trueButtonGeometry.firstMaterial = greenMaterial
    trueButton.geometry = trueButtonGeometry
    trueButton.name = "True"

    //3. Create A False Button With An SCNPlane Geometry & A Red Colour
    let falseButton = SCNNode();
    let falseButtonGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
    let redMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    redMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    redMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    falseButtonGeometry.firstMaterial = redMaterial
    falseButton.geometry = falseButtonGeometry
    falseButton.name = "False"

    //4. Set The Buttons Postions
    trueButton.position = SCNVector3(-0.2,0,0)
    falseButton.position = SCNVector3(0.2,0,0)

    //5. Add The Buttons To The Menu Node & Set Its Position
    menu.addChildNode(trueButton)
    menu.addChildNode(falseButton)
    menu.position = SCNVector3(0,0, -1.5)

    //6. Add The Menu To The View
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(menu)

}
```

Now let's look at using two `SCNNodes` as 'virtual buttons' using an `SCNTextGeometry`:

```
/// Creates A Menu With A True Or False Button Using SCNText Geometry
func createTrueOrFalseMenuWithText(){

    //1. Create A Menu Holder
    let menu = SCNNode()

    //2. Create A True Button With An SCNText Geometry & Green Colour
    let trueButton = SCNNode();
    let trueTextGeometry = SCNText(string: "True" , extrusionDepth: 1)
    trueTextGeometry.font = UIFont(name: "Helvatica", size: 3)
    trueTextGeometry.flatness = 0
    trueTextGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
    trueButton.geometry = trueTextGeometry
    trueButton.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01 , 0.01)
    trueButton.name = "True"

    //3. Create A False Button With An SCNText Geometry & Red Colour
    let falseButton = SCNNode();
    let falseTextGeometry = SCNText(string: "False" , extrusionDepth: 1)
    falseTextGeometry.font = UIFont(name: "Helvatica", size: 3)
    falseTextGeometry.flatness = 0
    falseTextGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    falseButton.geometry = falseTextGeometry
    falseButton.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01 , 0.01)
    falseButton.name = "False"

    //4. Set The Buttons Postions
    trueButton.position = SCNVector3(-0.2,0,0)
    falseButton.position = SCNVector3(0.2,0,0)

    //5. Add The Buttons To The Menu Node & Set Its Position
    menu.addChildNode(trueButton)
    menu.addChildNode(falseButton)
    menu.position = SCNVector3(0,0, -1.5)

    //6. Add The Menu To The View
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(menu)
}
```

Now we have our different implementation setup, you then need to create some kind of logic to handle whether we touched the true or false button.

You will note that when creating the true or false button, I made use of their `name property` which will help us to determine which one was tapped e.g:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

//1. Get The Current Touch Location
guard let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView),

//2. Perform An SCNHitTest & Get The Node Touched
let hitTestNode = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil).first?.node else { return }

//3. Determine Whether The User Pressed True Or False & Handle Game Logic
if hitTestNode.name == "True"{

    print("User Has A Correct Answer")

}else if hitTestNode.name == "False"{

    print("User Has An InCorrect Answer")

   }
 }
```

**Update:** In order to detect which Virtual Button has been selected outside of standard touches, you have two options, one which determines whether the button is `inViewOfFrostum`or using an SCNHitTest based on a specified `CGPoint` e.g. the center of the screen

Looking at the first option, we need to take into consideration that the ARCamera has a Frostrum in which our content is shown:

[image]

You could then determine if the user had selected either virtualButton by creating a function to determine this. However, this isn't probably what you are after as this would mean that you would have to ensure that the SCNNode buttons where placed apart enough to ensure that only one would be in view at a time.

If you needed this option you would first need two `SCNNodes` e.g:

```
  var trueButton: SCNNode!
  var falseButton: SCNNode!
```

Then create a function like so:

```
/// Detects If An Object Is In View Of The Camera Frostrum
func detectButtonInFrostrumOfCamera(){

    //1. Get The Current Point Of View
    if let currentPointOfView = augmentedRealityView.pointOfView{

        if augmentedRealityView.isNode(trueButton, insideFrustumOf: currentPointOfView){

            print("True Button Is In View & Has Been Selected As The Answer")

        }

        if augmentedRealityView.isNode(falseButton, insideFrustumOf: currentPointOfView){

            print("False Button Is In View & Has Been Selected As The Answer")

        }
    }
}
```

Which you would then trigger in the following `delegate` callback e.g.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

    detectButtonInFrostrumOfCamera()

}
```

A more likely solution however is to perform a virtual raycast using a CGPoint as a reference.

In this example let's first create our `CGPoint var` which will refer to the center of the screen:

```
var screenCenter: CGPoint!
```

We will then set this in `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.screenCenter = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.height/2)

 }
```

We will then create a function which performs an `SCNHitTest` against the screen center to see if the points touches either the true or false button e.g:

```
/// Detects If We Have Intersected A Virtual Button
func detectIntersetionOfButton(){

    guard let rayCastTarget = self.augmentedRealityView?.hitTest(screenCenter, options: nil).first else { return }

    if rayCastTarget.node.name == "True"{

       print("User Has Selected A True Answer")

    }

    if rayCastTarget.node.name == "False"{

        print("User Has Selected A False Answer")

    }

}
```

Which again would be called in the following delegate callback:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

   detectIntersetionOfButton()
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick and awesome reply. I have created nodes for true and false already. I just wanted to know a way to touch true and false in the camera's view and not on the touchscreen. The idea of my project is to interact with virtual objects in the camera view and not the touchscreen. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oops silly me... ok I will update my post later today for you :)

Comment: Hey @Josh Robbins you are awesome..The first method that you suggested is basically moving the camera in the direction of true/false to detect them which is not what i want but thanks for showing that anyway...But i will give the 2nd method a try and let you know if this works for me..also just wanted to let you know that i have to select true/false using my hands/finger in the camera's view...anyways thanks for your awesome and detailed explanation. You are awesome:)

Answer (score 0):

@Josh Robbins - first I want to thank you for your kindness and the time and effort you take to you put into your answers.

I gave you credit for this interesting infomrative answer that can be adapted for many different uses and ways and also well explained (as always with your answers :-)